# Hash table linear probing data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

When using linear probing, why can't a load factor threshold of 1.1 be chose for a hash table?
Is that supposed to work for all the numbers?

Comment: Load factor of `1.1` would mean no. of entries > no. of buckets resulting in overflow. What really did you want to ask ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I forgot this, but thanks to izaak_pyzaak for reminding me.

If you're using linear probing, I'm going to make the assumption you're not *chaining your hash table*.

As Arunmu points out, unchained hash tables will overflow if the load threshold is greater than 1. This will corrupt the hash table at the very least, and likely cause the program to crash.

Most of the time, hash tables are implemented with a max load factor set to 0.75, because a load greater than 0.75 starts to be a performance hit, and exponentially increase the amount of collisions in the table. As a rule, most tables should be 2-3 times larger than the intended amount of records, to reduce collisions.

A load factor of 1 would mean the hash table is completely filled when it resizes; and before it resized, it would cause a reduction in the speed of hashing/searching on the table. A load factor of 1.1 on an *unchained hash table* would be a major problem, as stated before.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding the question partly, (or at all.) but...

It's because you can't have 1.1 elements. You either have 1 or 0 (or 2, 3, 4 ... n) elements. Again, you also can't have 5.5 elements; you can have 5 or 6, but not in between. If you're looking to increase your threshold after 1 elements, simply make the threshold 1.

Comment: Load factor is (n/m), where n is number of elements, and m is size of pointer table (if linked list and chaining). Therefore a load factor of 1.1 is possible

Comment: Ah - thanks for educating me. I'll keep my incorrect answer up because I'm sure someone similarly doesn't understand.